# Moving item in lists with functions

Tags: python, list, function

My code runs but I'm expecting my `orders` to follow 3,2,1.
To my knowledge `pop()` takes the last entry and returns it.
So on my last call `move_to_old_orders(made_orders)` it returns in the list 1,2,3.
If you look in the output it goes from **3,2,1 / 3,2,1 / 1, 2, 3**.
The print statements at the end are for me to verify the list is empty and has moved.

Code:

```
unmade_orders = ['order 1' , 'order 2', 'order 3']
made_orders = []
old_orders = []

def make_orders(unmade_orders, made_orders):
    ''' To make an order '''
    while unmade_orders:
        current_order = unmade_orders.pop()
        print("Order Processing: " + current_order.title() + ".")

        made_orders.append(current_order)

def print_orders(made_orders):
    ''' To print an order '''
    for made_order in made_orders:
        print("Order Processed: " + made_order.title() + ".")

make_orders(unmade_orders, made_orders)
print_orders(made_orders)

def move_to_old_orders(made_orders):
    while made_orders:
        current_order_1 = made_orders.pop()
        print("Moving Order To Old Orders: " + current_order_1.title() + ".")

        old_orders.append(current_order_1)

move_to_old_orders(made_orders)

print(unmade_orders)
print(made_orders)
print(old_orders)
```

Output:

```
Order Processing: Order 3.
Order Processing: Order 2.
Order Processing: Order 1.
Order Processed: Order 3.
Order Processed: Order 2.
Order Processed: Order 1.
Moving Order To Old Orders: Order 1.
Moving Order To Old Orders: Order 2.
Moving Order To Old Orders: Order 3.
```

Comment: Seems like something is missing in the print output. Where is the final print of all the orders, specifically "old orders"?

Comment: `make_orders()` processes the list of `unmade_orders` in reverse, and appends them to `made_orders`, so it prints `3,2,1`. `print_orders()` prints `made_orders` in order, which is also `3,2.1`. `move_to_old_orders()` processes `made_orders` in reverse, so it prints `1,2,3`. I don't see the confusion.

Comment: @ShayNehmad Its located at the end with my other two print statements thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your function `make_orders()`
 is appending the list `make_orders = []` in this `make_orders = ["order 3","order 2","order 1"]` kind of format as it should be,
 'cause it's the nature of `append()`

That's why when you call the function `move_to_old_orders()` 
It starts from the last element which is `order 1`

That's why you are getting the output of `1 2 3`

Comment: Thank you, for the reply I get it now thank you!